# Why is this function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:A \to B$ where $A$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose
$$\lVert f(y_1) - f(y_2)\rVert_{\ell_\infty} \geq C\lVert y_1 - y_2 \rVert_{\ell_\infty}$$

This tells us that $f$ is one to one and that the inverse is Lipschitz.

I am told that $f$ is bi-Lipschitz; so $f$ is also Lipschitz, but I don't see why?

Comment: $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ on $[0,1]$ satisfies your inequality with $C=1/2$, but it's not Lipschitz.

Comment: What is the $\ell_\infty$ norm for $\mathbb{R}^n$  ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Just the usual thing: $\lVert x \rVert = \sup_i |x_i|$

Comment: @Cantor I see. Suppose we say that $f \in W^{1,\infty}(A).$ Does weak differentiability suffice?

Comment: This is not just differentiability, this is differentiability with derivative in $L^{\infty}$ and therefore it is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @user67133 I can only see it is true when $f'$ is linear. What if it's nonlinear? Sorry for m y slowness..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was inaccurate: in the general settings of your problem, where the only thing we know on $A$ is that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, it is not true that even if $f \in W^{1,\infty}(A)$ then $f \in \text{Lip}(A)$. Neverthless what is true is the following:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Leu $U$ be open and bounded, with $\partial U$ of class $C^1$. Then $u \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous if and aonly if $u \in W^{1,\infty}(U)$.

This is proved in Evan's Partial Differential Equations: this is Th. 4 of the additional topics in chapter 5.
For the case in which $U$ is unbounded you just need to read the section dedicated to extentions.

The theoreom is pretty good, indeed any weakening of the hypothesis makes the theorem false: google has counterexamples. (Even the Hypothesis $\partial U$ of Lipschitz class is too weak.)

If your $A$ is a general open set what is true is that $u \in W^{1,\infty}_{loc}(A) \Longleftrightarrow u \in \text{Lip}_{loc}(A)$.

I really hope this helps!